# Redirect user to login page if not authenthicated

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to get the url redirect to /login everytime user is not authenticated including going to the base url. E.g. localhost:8080 -> localhost:8080/login. Any help is appreciated!

This is my login controller

```
public class LoginController {

@Autowired
LoginService service;


/*
 *  Map /login to this method 
 *  localhost:8080/spring-mvc/login
 *  spring-mvc -> dispatcher (todo-servlet.xml)
 *  dispatcher detects login url
 *  dispatcher use view resolver to find .jsp file based on String. In this case, login
 *  view resolver locates login.jsp and shows the content to user via http
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/test")

@ResponseBody
public String test() {
    return "Hello, world!";
}

@RequestMapping(value ="/")
public String returnLogin() {
    return "redirect:/loginPage";
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public String loginPage() { 

    return "login";
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method= RequestMethod.POST)
has an addition function where it allows a collection of attributes
public String handleLogin(@RequestParam String name, @RequestParam String password, ModelMap model) {
    if (service.validateUser(name, password)) {
    
    model.addAttribute("name", name);
    model.addAttribute("passWelcome", password);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
    String date = sdf.format(new Date());
    model.addAttribute("date", date);
    }
    
    else {
        model.put("errorMessage","Invalid credentials");
        return loginPage();
    }
    return "welcome";
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need `cookies` so that you can track user activities, this is usually what every website with login functionality must have.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advice you to add Spring Security in the project. It will do all that for you; you will not need to manage the sessions and check if the user is login or not etc. Spring security will do it for you. Spring security will automatically redirect the user to the login page if the user is not authenticated.